# SonarLint fails to bind solution in Connected Mode

Tags: visual-studio, sonarqube, sonarlint

We are attempting to use SonarLint with a SonarQube server in order to do static analysis on our code.  Installing SonarLint into Visual Studio works fine, but when I attempt to bind the solution to a SonarQube project, I get this error message in Team Explorer.

"Failed to bind the solution to SonarQube project, try again.
See more information in the output window (SonarLint)."

When I check the output window, this is the last message.

"Binding solution to SonarQube project: Generating project rule sets"

- SonarQube Version 6.5 (build 27846)
- SonarLint Version 3.7.0.2645
- Sonar Analyzer C# Version 5.10.1.1411

I have attempted to update the Sonar Analyzer with Nuget, but that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: It is possible that SonarLint timeouts when trying to download the quality profile from SonarQube. I am not sure if it will help, but could you please provide the versions of SonarLint, SonarQube and SonarC# that you have?

Comment: I have seen that SonarLint successfully downloads the quality profile before it attempts to bind the solutions and I have edited the question to include the information asked for.

Comment: The next steps in the binding workflow are actually updating the projects and there is no logging inside, I cannot precisely say what could be wrong, but you could see if you have incompatible projects (.NET Core for example) or you could first check-out (if you use TFS) the project files, then try to bind. On a side note, unrelated to the problem, to update SonarC# you need to do it from SonarQube, then rebind from SonarLint.